# pass data between viewpager on change/swipe fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, send

im searching for some while to find a solution to send data between fragments not on click any button but only on swipe and/ or click on Bottom nav bar,

So in my case i have a Viewpager and three Fragments in the same Activity. on the first Fragment i have a seekbar that is showing me a progress in a Textview and same on the second fragment. i want to pass each textview integer to two textviews on the third fragment. But this should be done when i swipe to the last fragment. hope you understand what i want to do and can help.

I tried to implement OnPause and OnStop but it does not work. Is there a any other method i can call ? i understand that if i change the view to other fragment there should be a call like onswipe or onchangeview to call the command to send data to the last fragment.

My XML files 
fragment_holding(for PageOne) has a seekbar and a Textview that is displaying the progress
fragment_wind(for PageTwo) has a seekbar and a Textview that is displaying the progress
fragment_answer(for PageTree) has two Textview to diplay the progress of each seekbar

**FragmentAdapter**

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> Fragment = new ArrayList<>(); //Fragment List
private List<String> NamePage = new ArrayList<>(); // Fragment Name List
public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}
public void add(Fragment Frag, String Title) {
    Fragment.add(Frag);
    NamePage.add(Title);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return Fragment.get(position);
}
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return NamePage.get(position);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
ViewPager viewPager;
BottomNavigationView navigation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager); //Init Viewpager
    setupFm(getSupportFragmentManager(), viewPager); //Setup Fragment
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0); //Set Currrent Item When Activity Start
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new PageChange()); //Listeners For Viewpager When Page Changed



}
public static void setupFm(FragmentManager fragmentManager, ViewPager viewPager){
    FragmentAdapter Adapter = new FragmentAdapter(fragmentManager);
    //Add All Fragment To List
    Adapter.add(new PageOne(), "Page One");
    Adapter.add(new PageTwo(), "Page Two");
    Adapter.add(new PageTree(), "Page Three");
    viewPager.setAdapter(Adapter);
}
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
public class PageChange implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_home);
                break;
            case 1:
                navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_dashboard);
                break;
            case 2:
                navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_notifications);
                break;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
}
```

**PageOne**
public class PageOne extends Fragment {

```
private SeekBar sbar;
private TextView tView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_holding, null);
    sbar =(SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar5);
    tView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    tView.setText(sbar.getProgress() + "/" + sbar.getMax());


    sbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int pval = 0;
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            pval = progress;
            tView.setText(pval + "/" + seekBar.getMax());




        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //write custom code to on start progress
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

**PageTwo**

```
public class PageTwo extends Fragment {

private SeekBar sbar4;
private TextView tView4;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wind, null);



    sbar4 =(SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar5);
    tView4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    tView4.setText(sbar4.getProgress() + "/" + sbar4.getMax());


    sbar4.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int pval = 0;

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            pval = progress;
            tView4.setText(pval + "/" + seekBar.getMax());

        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //write custom code to on start progress
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

**PageTree**

public class PageTree extends Fragment {

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_answer, container, false);





    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Adapter do this :-

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        GridFragment gridFragment = new GridFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("position", position);
        bundle.putString("survayType", survayType);
        bundle.putInt("questionNo", questionNo);
        gridFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return gridFragment;
    }
```

and in your fragment do like this :-

```
        optionPosition = getArguments().getInt("position");
        survayType = getArguments().getString("survayType");
        questionNo = getArguments().getInt("questionNo");
```